# DTEdit fails to update database. It returns "object 'datatables_html' not found" when I click on save button to update SQL table

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I am trying to edit a table using the R DTEdit package implemented in shiny. However, it fails to update database. I have the code below, however, when I click on save button to update the PostGresql table shiny returns

> "object 'datatables_html' not found"

I need to update SQL tables using shiny as a frontend interface.

```
library(DTedit)
library(shiny, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DT, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(pool, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(shinyjs, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(uuid, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(RPostgres)
library(data.table)
library(DBI)

db <- '******'  #provide the name of your db
host_db <- "ddddddd" #i.e. # i.e. 'ec2-54-83-201-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com'  
db_port <- 'ddddd'  # or any other port specified by the DBA
db_user <- "ddddddd"  
db_password <- "ddddddd"

pool <- dbPool(RPostgres::Postgres(), db = db, host = host_db, user = db_user, password = db_password)
conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = db, host = host_db, port = db_port, user = db_user, password = db_password)
onStop(function() {poolClose(pool)})
##### Load books data.frame as a SQLite database
# conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "books.sqlite")

if(!'books' %in% dbListTables(conn)) {
  books <- read.csv('books.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  books$Authors <- strsplit(books$Authors, ';')
  books$Authors <- lapply(books$Authors, trimws) # Strip white space
  books$Authors <- unlist(lapply(books$Authors, paste0, collapse = ';'))
  books$id <- 1:nrow(books)
  books$Date <- paste0(books$Date, '-01-01')
  dbWriteTable(conn, "books", books, overwrite = TRUE)
}

getBooks <- function() {
  res <- dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM books")
  books <- dbFetch(res)
  dbClearResult(res)
  books$Authors <- strsplit(books$Authors, ';')
  books$Date <- as.Date(books$Date, origin='1970-01-01')
  books$Publisher <- as.factor(books$Publisher)
  return(books)
}

##### Callback functions.
books.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
  query <- paste0("INSERT INTO books (id, Authors, Date, Title, Publisher) VALUES (",
                  "", max(getBooks()$id) + 1, ", ",
                  "'", paste0(data[row,]$Authors[[1]], collapse = ';'), "', ",
                  "'", as.character(data[row,]$Date), "', ",
                  "'", data[row,]$Title, "', ",
                  "'", as.character(data[row,]$Publisher), "' ",
                  ")")
  print(query) # For debugging
  dbSendQuery(conn, query)
  return(getBooks())
}

books.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
  query <- paste0("UPDATE books SET ",
                  "Authors = '", paste0(data[row,]$Authors[[1]], collapse = ';'), "', ",
                  "Date = '", as.character(data[row,]$Date), "', ",
                  "Title = '", data[row,]$Title, "', ",
                  "Publisher = '", as.character(data[row,]$Publisher), "' ",
                  "WHERE id = ", data[row,]$id)
  print(query) # For debugging
  dbSendQuery(conn, query)
  return(getBooks())
}

books.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
  query <- paste0('DELETE FROM books WHERE id = ', data[row,]$id)
  dbSendQuery(conn, query)
  return(getBooks())
}

##### Create the Shiny server
server <- function(input, output) {
  books <- getBooks()
  dtedit(input, output,
         name = 'books',
         thedata = books,
         edit.cols = c('Title', 'Authors', 'Date', 'Publisher'),
         edit.label.cols = c('Book Title', 'Authors', 'Publication Date', 'Publisher'),
         input.types = c(Title='textAreaInput'),
         input.choices = list(Authors = unique(unlist(books$Authors))),
         view.cols = c('Title', 'Authors', 'Date', 'Publisher'),
         callback.update = books.update.callback,
         callback.insert = books.insert.callback,
         callback.delete = books.delete.callback)
  
  names <- data.frame(Name=character(), Email=character(), Date=numeric(),
                      Type = factor(levels=c('Admin', 'User')),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names$Date <- as.Date(names$Date, origin='1970-01-01')
  namesdt <- dtedit(input, output, name = 'names', names)
}

##### Create the shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('Books'),
  uiOutput('books'),
  hr(), h3('Email Addresses'),
  uiOutput('names')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```